# Using node-http-proxy, changing url with proxyRequest

Tags: node.js, node-http-proxy

When modifying a [node-http-proxy example](https://github.com/sequoiar/node-http-proxy/blob/30ef8989e2e1b8f7a21dca36962b5c0ad8966e10/examples/http/standalone-proxy.js)...

**The Issue:**  When manually changing the `req.headers.host` to a remote host ('example.com'), the url in the the browser is not changing.

**Note:** I thought this was working, however when using google.com as my example, it turned out google was detecting the proxy and changing the host.

**Question:** Is there a way to change the url in the browser to a remote host (ie. example.com), everytime? Thanks!

```
var util = require('util'),
    colors = require('colors'),
    http = require('http'),
    httpProxy = require('../../lib/node-http-proxy');

//
// Http Server with proxyRequest Handler and Latency
//
var proxy = new httpProxy.RoutingProxy();
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  req.headers.host = 'example.com'; // manually setting example.com
  var buffer = httpProxy.buffer(req);
  setTimeout(function () {
    proxy.proxyRequest(req, res, {
      port: 80,
      host: 'example.com',
      buffer: buffer
    });
  }, 200);
}).listen(8004);



util.puts('http server '.blue + 'started '.green.bold + 'on port '.blue + '8004 '.yellow + 'with proxyRequest handler'.cyan.underline + ' and latency'.magenta);
util.puts('http server '.blue + 'started '.green.bold + 'on port '.blue + '9000 '.yellow);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few solutions that will do this are:

- Issue a 301 redirect.
- Use IPTables to DNAT and change the desination address.
- Use TPROXY to transparently proxy the requests without modifying the
  packets.